# Telegram Bot - NodeJs - Tasks are on a loop

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

Sometimes; my telegram bots start repeating the same tasks multiple times on a loop.

**Sometimes; it repeats the tasks 500 times !!! 
This is very annoying.**

Context that I can't reproduced :

- User send a command only once (click on one button)
- my event listenr is triggered ( `bot.on("callback_query"` or  `bot.on('message')`);
- action is executed
- and then... it starts again !!! and again... and again..

Mainly it is happening on :

```
bot.on("callback_query", function(callbackQuery) {
```

and on

```
bot.on('message', function(event) {
```

> Do you guys have experienced this kind of issue ?
>   How do you manage that kind of issues ?

Comment: Any log on the server side that you have generated for the same?

Comment: can you explain your question a little more please,  The problem could be on the handler's function. Can you post a snippet part of your event handlers

Comment: Maybe you added the listener multiple times?

Comment: I am willing to help you, for that I need to be able to see the code... Otherwise it will only be guessing... [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MY issue seems to be linked to Firebase integration.
As my database is updated; it seems to generate a trigger on my telegram bot in realtime.

This is really wierd .... don't know yet how to solve it; but so far; this is my issue.

Answer (score 1):

> bot.on('message', function(event) {

`the message can be of any type`, eg, text, a new chat member etc..

you might be looking for a some type of messages say text audio, etc,

in that case you can use onText() to get only messages, or add a check for the message type inside on('message')

Answer (score 1):

You need to check `callbackQuery` and `event` parameters and look for the changes if any or the data that you are receiving in the callbacks.
If the old data is different from the new data then execute the rest of the code otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

```
bot.on("callback_query", function(callbackQuery) {
```

Guessing by your answer

> MY issue seems to be linked to Firebase integration. As my database is updated;

Firebase nodejs library is realtime and the on listener will trigger on any value that changes in the tree of the path on which you have subscribed. In that case, to minimize trigger points, I would recommend the following:

I suppose you might be putting an on listener on some base path with multiple json values inside. Instead of that you could have something like below:

```
// a.firebaseio.com/x -> some firebase path on which you have on listener
y: {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2,
    .
    .
    key200: value200
}
```

Here, whichever values change, your on listener will be triggered. Now I suppose you are inherently interested only in change of some values (say value 1 and value 2)

> One way to handle is to do multiwrite

Multiwrite will ensure that all your writes are at once and that will trigger only one on listener event

> Second approach is to keep track of lastUpdated timestamp

Lets imagine a second structure

```
// a.firebaseio.com/x -> some firebase path on which you have on listener
y: {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2,
    .
    .
    key200: value200
},
lastUpdatedTs: <epochTs>
```

> You put your on listener on lastUpdatedTs and update it using multiwrite whenever you are updating something important inside y object. Whenever lastUpdatedTs changes, you go ahead and do a firebase fetch on y. This enables you to throttle much better and not let firebase on listener on the data go rogue inside your code.